# Best solution to compare/ search multiple integers with in an array

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, compare, lookup

I just wanted to ask you what's the most efficient solution to do the following comparison:

I am getting a value from my function. For example `6`. Now I want to compare that with multiple integers and if it same(`true`), otherwise(`false`) like a typical `if-statement`.

For now, I have used an `array` but I am pretty sure it's very unnecessary to for each array elements, all the time to check if the value is in it or not.

Can anyone show me a more accurate and efficient way?

Regards

Comment: You should open your C++ book that explains how to use a `std::unordered_set`, and start reading.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik thats the proper solution.

Comment: if the range of numbers is not too big, you might even consider using a `std::vector<bool>`.

Comment: You may also sort your array of and use `std::binary_search`.

Comment: Isn't it mostly the same as the solution I am using right now? @SamVarshavchik

Comment: On the unsorted array you have a worst case complexity of O(n). With `std::unordered_set` and `vector<bool>` it is O(1), while `vector<bool>` is even faster but depending on the range you may have a bad memory foot print. Finally, when you don't have a lot of changes in the array you may sort it (O(n*log(n)) and use `binary_search` O(log(n)), this variant has the smallest memory foot print.

Comment: It's "mostly the same" only as in producing the same result. But it is the more "efficient" approach, as you desired.

Answer (score 1):

As @Sam Varshavchik already mentioned in the comments, you can use [`std::unordered_set<>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) to store all the values in the array and its [`std::unordered_set::find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/find) for look up, which has a **constant time** complexity on average case.

Following is the sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>

int fun()
{
   /* return some integer */
   return 1;
}

int main()
{
   std::unordered_set<int> Arr = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
   std::cout << std::boolalpha << (Arr.find( fun() ) != Arr.cend());
   // or
   // (Arr.find( fun() ) != Arr.cend()) ?  std::cout << "Found\n": std::cout << "Not Found\n";

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You may also consider using `(Arr.count(fun()) > 0)`, which is a bit more intuitive.

Comment: @kiloalphaindia In this case, yes that is an alternative. But in the context of searching, using *find* is more readable code to me.

Comment: I tend to use `count(...)` for `set`-types and `find(...)` for `map`-types. But it`s only a matter of taste, your answer is still correct of cause. (Vote up)

Answer (score 1):

To add to previous answers, here's a simple benchmark comparing `unordered_set` with `vector`/`find` and `vector`/`binary_search`.

<kbd>[**Live Demo**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/JFWPw8Cc6SjqeiXx)</kbd>

```
#include <iostream>

#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <random>
#include <boost/timer/timer.hpp>

std::random_device rd;     // only used once to initialise (seed) engine
std::mt19937 rng(rd());    // random-number engine used (Mersenne-Twister in this case)
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> uni(0, 6); // guaranteed unbiased

int fun()
{
   /* return some integer */
   return uni(rng);
}

const size_t nTries = 1000000;
int main()
{  
   volatile bool isFound;
   { // unordered_set
   std::unordered_set<int> vals = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
   {
   boost::timer::auto_cpu_timer timer;
   for(volatile size_t i=0; i<nTries; i++)
       isFound = (vals.find(fun()) != vals.cend());
   }     
   }

   { // vector
   std::vector<int> vals = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
   {
   boost::timer::auto_cpu_timer timer;
   for(volatile size_t i=0; i<nTries; i++)
       isFound = (std::find(vals.cbegin(), vals.cend(), fun()) != vals.cend());
   }
   }

   { // vector, binary search
   std::vector<int> vals = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
   std::sort (vals.begin(), vals.end());
   {
   boost::timer::auto_cpu_timer timer;
   for(volatile size_t i=0; i<nTries; i++)
       isFound = std::binary_search (vals.cbegin(), vals.cend(), fun());
   }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Numbers are varying quite a bit and gcc and clang behave differently, but it seems that using `unordered_set` is a safe bet.

Comment: nice...! However, you missed the vector<bool> variant. (vote up)

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the advices!

My new solution(@SamVarshavchik suggestion)  looks like this now:

```
std::unorderet_set<int> values= { 7, 8, 10, 13, 14, 16, 60, 17, 19, 24, 26, 27, 28, 33, 34, 39 };

bool check_value() {


    if (values.find( grabvalues() ) != values.cend()) { return true; }
    else { return false; }


}
```

Comment: `return values.find(grabvalues()) != values.end()`